# Calendar table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create a table that contains a single column of date data type, that consists of all days starting from Jan 1, 2000 until today  in oracle SQL

Comment: What DBMS are you using? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) This sounds like homework, if it is it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Create a table using CREATE table statement, in your client code (e.g. Java program) write a loop to insert all the date values you need.

Comment: u can find answer from http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=58479. just google "get all the dates between two dates in sql"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Oracle row generator](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques):

```
 insert into your_table ( your_column )
 select 
    to_date('2000/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') + N.n
 from
  (SELECT ROWNUM n
   FROM   ( SELECT 1 just_a_column
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 
               SYSDATE
               - to_date('2000/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
               + 1
           ) T
  ) N
  where
      to_date('2000/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') + N.n <= SYSDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

As your question is not clear, I'm assuming you want like this.

SQL server Platform.

```
CREATE table mycalender
(
mydate date
);

declare @startdate as date = '2000-01-01'

WHILE(@startdate!=DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())))
begin
insert into mycalender VALUES(@startdate)
set @startdate=dateadd(day,1,@startdate)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is MS SQL Server try this:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = '20000101';
DECLARE @DateTo DATETIME = GETDATE();

WITH Dates(date)
AS
( 
SELECT @DateFrom 
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day,1,Dates.date) FROM Dates WHERE Dates.date < DATEADD(DAY, -1, @DateTo)
)

SELECT * FROM Dates OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5000);
```